# Select cell copy from worksheet to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Need your advise and help on how to copy multiple cell (one by one) in sheet1 to single cell in sheet2.

Every single button click will copy single cell of sheet1 to sheet2 cell"B4"

Herewith is my sample code:

---

```
Dim lRow, RowIndex As Long
Dim src As Worksheet, dest As Worksheet

Dim rng As Range

Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
lRow = src.Range("D8").End(xlDown).Row
RowIndex = 1

    For Each rng In src.Range("D8:D" & lRow)



    src.Range(rng & RowIndex).Copy Destination:=dest.Range("B4")

    Selection.Copy

    RowIndex = RowIndex + 1


    Next rng


Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

---

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try following sub

```
Sub CopyToSingleCell()
Dim lRow, RowIndex As Long
Dim src As Worksheet, dest As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
    lRow = src.Range("D8").End(xlDown).Row

        For Each rng In src.Range("D8:D" & lRow)
            dest.Range("B4") = dest.Range("B4") & " " & rng.Value
        Next rng

    Set src = Nothing
    Set dest = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Really Thanks for your sharing.

I have tested the code but it seems that the three values of D8:D10 (in sheet 1) appear together in B4 (in sheet 2) at the same time, but not one by one.

May I know if there is any other possible solution.

Thanks again!